# Angular values update in both elements

Tags: angularjs

I am adding same element (json object) into a list (from another list) twice using .copy to break the reference. But even after doing that when I change some values in one both of them are getting updated.

> ```
>         $scope.addProduct = function (item) {
>         var index = $scope.itemsProduct.indexOf(item); 
>         $scope.scopItem = {};
>         angular.copy(item , $scope.scopItem); 
>         for(var j in  $scope.scopItem['ABC']) {                                
>             $scope.scopItem['ABC'][j].dataType='Discount';
>             $scope.scopItem['ABC'][j]['Discount'] = '';                              
>         } 
>         if (index != -1) { 
>             $scope.itemsTags.push($scope.scopItem); 
>             $timeout(function() {
>                 $scope.$apply(function () { 
>                     $scope.calculate($scope.scopItem);
>                 });
>             }, 10);
>         }
>     };
> ```

`$scope.calculateParam = function (indexQ) {
     var index = $scope.itemsTags.indexOf(indexQ); 
     $scope.itemsTags[index]['ABC']['Discount'] = '10'; //or some other logic
}`

Need help as even i am not adding the same element(using .copy) and updating the "Discount" property of one updates both?? 
Note: ABC is a inner list with property as "Discount" and I am changing "Discount"

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

```
for(var j in  $scope.scopItem['ABC'])
```

it's absolutely incorrect and should be rewrited to

```
for(var j=0; j < $scope.scopItem['ABC'].length; j++)
```

also `scopItem` is changed in calculate method and stored in itemsTags

Comment: scopItem is changes in calculate function but I am only adding new values in it on conditions like : var index itemSQ = $scope.itemsTags.indexOf(indexQ) where indexQ = scopItem.

Comment: 'indexQ' and '$scope.itemsTags[index]' - are the same objects, it's one reference. But '$scope.itemsTags[index]['ABC']' - is array, doesn't have Discount property

Comment: yes they are same- but '$scope.itemsTags[index]['ABC']' has "discount" property..

Comment: $scope.itemsTags[index]['ABC'] has discount property, becaouse bug in loop for(var j in  $scope.scopItem['ABC'])